# Why there's error in onclick when i have "module" in script tag?

Tags: javascript

I have button with function and it looks like this :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

And there's main.js file :

```
function myFunction(){
   console.log('Button has been clicked');
}
```

Without module type in script tag it works fine but when there's module type in it, console throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.myFunction is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

How to fix it to work fine with module?

Comment: I think you miss the whole point of modules.  Think `import` and `export`, without using them, modules makes no sense.

Comment: I believe you need to do some more research on modules: https://javascript.info/modules-intro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default scope in modules is *the module* and not global.

Attach event handlers using `addEventListener` in JavaScript instead of intrinsic event attributes in HTML.